# How can i use jQuery selector inside (tornado) template tag?

Tags: jquery, python, html, tornado

I hope i am asking the right question. Basically, i have python/tornado app and i have an issue populating two combo boxes in my html page. I am trying to populate the second combo box  depending on the selected value in the first one. In my python settings file i have json data with following structure:

```
data = {'A':{
            '1': {}, 
            '2': {}, 
            '3': {}
            }, 
        'B': {
             '3': {}, 
             '4': {} 
             }
       }
```

The first combo box contains values A and B, and if A is selected then the second combo box should contain 1, 2 and 3... I try to load it like this:

```
{% block filter1 %}
<select id="filter1">
{% for key in settings.data %}
    <option value="{{ key }}">{{key}}</option>
{% end %}
</select>
{% end %}

{% block filter2 %}
<select id="filter2">
{% for key in settings.data[$("#filter1").val()] %}
    <option value="{{ key }}">{{key}}</option>
{% end %}
</select>
{% end %}
```

The problem is obviously settings.data[$("#filter1").val()], it's both serverside and clientside code, and i cannot use it like that. Is there an 'easy' way to get that kind of behavior? Am i maybe missing something obvious, or should i use some different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is the issue

> {% for key in settings.data[$("#filter1").val()] %}

There is no getting around having this work up front though. Since this is going to be dependent on client interaction, the code to handle that interaction must be client side.

What this means is that you will need to do this with javascript and not simply server side code (unless there is a helper for generating this type of javascript). Essentially it will be along the lines of a script tag or reference, an onchange event, and some sort of population logic which draws on elements on the page or perhaps some sort of json storage.